# How to rewrite query, which uses aggregate function and group by

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So, I have a quite large table (date-partitioned), e.g table1. There is multicolumn index on (shop_id, g_id, check_date).

And I'm trying to run the query:

```
SELECT shop_id, g_id, max(check_date)
FROM table1
GROUP BY shop_id, g_id;
```

The execution is really slow - Seq Scan.
How to optimize/rewrite the query, so it may use index.
There also a table which contains unique G_IDs and another table with unique SHOP_IDs.

Comment: you can switch off sec scan temporarily with `enable_secscan to off` and check if index scan wild be benefitial, if so at least reanalyze the table

Comment: @VaoTsun Sure, that gonna make index_scan work, but the query plan is still awfull

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite this query using analytic functions, e.g.

```
SELECT
    t.shop_id,
    t.g_id,
    t.check_date
FROM
(
    SELECT shop_id, g_id, check_date,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY shop_id, g_id ORDER BY check_date DESC) dr
    FROM table1
) t
WHERE t.dr = 1;
```

Add an index on both the `shop_id` and `g_id` columns to cover the entire partition:

```
CREATE INDEX your_idx ON table1 (shop_id, g_id);
```

Comment: It doesn't really helps.Subquery Scan on t  (cost=75752739.31..89811591.81 rows=2008408 width=16). When previous query QUERY PLAN
HashAggregate  (cost=14497422.24..14505112.79 rows=769055 width=16)

Comment: @AntonBondar Add an index on the columns involved in the partition.